# Can't set default project language with Visual Web Developer 2008 Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-express, vwdexpress

This seems like a very basic feature to me. I can't seem to set C# as the default programming language for Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition. I've searched and searched and found nothing useful. Any ideas?

The reason why MVC is tagged is because it auto generates controllers and all that jazz -- in the wrong language.

Comment: Probably doesn't belong in asp.net-mvc.  Suggest you retag to visual-studio-express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new project, the 'Project types' panel on the left should list 'Visual Basic' and 'Visual C#'. Select a project from the 'Visual C#' list.

When you create a new website there should be a 'Language' drop down at the bottom left of the dialog to select 'Visual C#'

If these options are not available to you then I would guess that C# wasn't installed when you installed VWD 2008 Express

Comment: It's a shame that it can't be changed after the fact but I guess it auto generates files right away and that may be why